# aiohttp can't work in docker container on AWS

Tags: python, aiohttp

aiohttp works fine on local machine, but can't work when deployment in AWS cluster.

`

```
    async def _get_file_size(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=self.auth) as client:
            async with client.get(self.asf_url) as size_session:
                self.file_size = size_session.content_length
```

`
Different client object is obtained when on local machine and AWS cluster

Comment: What you mean by `Different Client`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @aramcpp Sorry not to declaim my question clearly. In other words, it returns different url on local machine and AWS EC2. Seems like problem on proxy